# Assigning a rails value to a global variable and use it in javascript

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I have a javascript function which takes rails value like

```
<body onload="myFunction(<%p%>)">
```

and I'm trying to pass a value coming from the controller like this

```
<% if logged_in? -%><%p= current_user.id %><% end -%> but here the p doesn't contain the value. this works if I put code like this
<body onload="myFunction(<%= current_user.id%>)">
<% if logged_in? -%><%= current_user.id %><% end -%>
```

But I need a further requirement, so another line like this should be add

```
<% if logged_out? -%><%p= current_user.id %><% end -%>
```

So if the user is logged out then the value p will passed to the javascript function. I know this is a small thing but don't know how to do it, I'm new to ror so please help and if you have tutorials to learn this point me too, so that can I save the time of both you and me in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope it will help:

[Passing Data to JavaScript](http://railscasts.com/episodes/324-passing-data-to-javascript)

Answer (score 0):

Please use like this when assign any value

```
      <body onload="myFunction('<%=p%>')">
```

Hope work it

Comment: another thing ,is this right <%p= current_user.id %>  kashif?

Comment: but this  <body onload="myFunction('<%=p%>')"> is not working..:(

Comment: But i thing better is you first set the id of user into p variable like this    p = current_user.id and then pass p variable to function

Comment: Sorry for disturbing you, do you know any ebook or tutorials to learn these things?

Comment: Rails guide is best also micheal hurt tutorial is best.But js you will learn with passage of time.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12289/discussion-between-kashif-ali-and-shamitha-silva)